# Any way to mass delete people?

Tags: league-of-legends

Although the question is pretty clear on the tittle I'll explain it a bit more.

I'm pretty tired of people asking me to duo every time I open the game maybe because I'm on a winning streak or quickly climbing divisions lately and having to tell them next time, or that I'm taking a break to not completely turn them down. I'd like to delete pretty much everyone except 2-3 people.

Now, as we all know the deleting process takes a while in League so I've been wondering if anyone knows a faster way, like accessing the game files or pretty much deleting many people at once so that it won't take me an hour to delete 200+ friends.

Comment: Deleting people requires three clicks, I'm not sure how that takes "a while". Your friends list is saved server side, not to any accessible local files, otherwise you would lose your friends list anytime you logged into a new computer.

Comment: And furthermore there is no API for such operations or a console and that's why you probably cant do what you want. Another way could be the support of riot. Maybe they can delete your whole friend list and you could readd your 2-3 friends.

Comment: It won't help too much now, but you could put all these people into a group when you add them so that you can hide them all with one click

Answer (score 1):

Set a mouse-macro to run the sequence of actions required to delete someone and wait for it to finish.